# How to inject a mock Assembly for use with Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, model-view-controller, moq, assemblies

There is a method in my controller that returns attribute data from the current executing assembly into a partial view.

In this example, I'm merely pulling the Title, but I need to do more with it.

**Controller:**

```
    var title = "";

    var asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    var attrs = asm.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AssemblyTitleAttribute));
    var titleAttr = (AssemblyTitleAttribute)attributes[0];

    title = titleAttr.Title;

    return PartialView("_Build", title);
```

When writing the unit test in Moq, I need to find a way to inject the Assembly attributes into a mock so that I can verify that the correct attributes are being generated when I run the controller test, and then do x or y with my asserts.

**UnitTest:**

```
    //Arrange
    //The magic I need to happen.

    //Act
    var controller = GetController();
    var result = controller.MyMethod() as PartialViewResult;
    var title = result.Model;

    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual("Title", title); //currently static, need to verify against a mock
```

I know this is an extremely simple set of code, but I just need proof of concept at this point.

Is there a good way to create a fake Assembly?
Do I need to use System.Reflection.Emit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a virtual method e.g. `GetCustomAttributes` which provides the attributes for given type.  Then in your test preject a *testable* class would derive from the controller class and override this method.

> Home Controller:

```
private IDependency _someDependency;

public HomeController(IDependency someDependency)
{
    _someDependency = someDependency;
}

public ActionResult MyMethod()
{
    var title = "";
    var version = "";

    IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes = GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AssemblyVersionAttribute)).ToList();
    AssemblyVersionAttribute verAttr = attributes.OfType<AssemblyVersionAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
    if (verAttr != null) version = verAttr.Version;

    attributes = GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AssemblyTitleAttribute)).ToList();
    AssemblyTitleAttribute titleAttr = attributes.OfType<AssemblyTitleAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
    if (titleAttr != null) title = titleAttr.Title;

    return PartialView("_Build", title + version);
}

public virtual IEnumerable<Attribute> GetCustomAttributes(Type attributeType)
{
    var asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    var attrs = asm.GetCustomAttributes(attributeType);
    return attrs;
}
```

> Test:

```
[TestClass]
public class MyMethodTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void MyMethod_WhenCalled_PartialViewIsReturned()
    {
        // Arrange
        // The magic I need to happen.

        Mock<IDependency> dependencyStub = new Mock<IDependency>();
        // dependencyStub.Setup(...).Returns(...);
        var controller = new TestableHomeController(dependencyStub.Object)
        {
            UseFakeAttributes = true
        };

        // Act
        var result = controller.MyMethod() as PartialViewResult;

        // Assert
        var model = result.Model;
        Assert.AreEqual("MyFakeTitle1.0.0.0", model); // currently static, need to verify against a mock
    }

    private class TestableHomeController : HomeController
    {
        public bool UseFakeAttributes { get; set; }

        public TestableHomeController(IDependency someDependency)
            :base(someDependency)
        { }

        public override IEnumerable<Attribute> GetCustomAttributes(Type attributeType)
        {
            return UseFakeAttributes
                ? new List<Attribute>
                    {
                        new AssemblyTitleAttribute("MyFakeTitle"),
                        new AssemblyVersionAttribute("1.0.0.0"),
                        new AssemblyDescriptionAttribute("Assembly fake description")
                        // next attributes ...
                    }.Where(a => a.GetType() == attributeType)
                : base.GetCustomAttributes(attributeType);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What if the controller inheritance enforces a constructor in the derived class?

Comment: @PhillipJenkins Then you create an overload that inherits from base. Not to worry--this is a solid Michael Feathers "working effectively with legacy code" approach to isolate problematic code. Note "legacy code"--if you're not currently experiencing this problem, it's not worth the time to try to think through the implications or "future-proof"; that time would be better spent just refactoring the code so the value is injected.

Comment: @PhillipJ see edited answer, the controller has a constructor with parameter which will be mocked and injected to testable class.

Comment: I was using this with Moq and once I figured out how to inject the Mock repositories into my fake controller class through constructor chaining, it worked like a dream.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is static type information, you only need to evaluate it once per build. Consider populating a static collection (e.g. a dictionary) with this information at application start. At that point you can inject your dictionary into the controller, or you can modify your configuration to access the dictionary and inject only the values you need. In fact, provided this doesn't get out of control, it might be best to just have named string instances like "build" or "title" without even having to house them in a collection.

I wouldn't mess with the hassle of trying to get unit tests around parsing an assembly attribute unless the logic can be contained in a static method that your unit tests call directly. From a web app perspective, it's best to leave this type of stuff out of the controller; the bootstrapper layer is a much more appropriate location.

Comment: This is a good refactoring change that probably needs to happen. I like this approach, but I'm not sure what effect this will have at the moment. Thanks for the info, I'll definitely take it to heart.