# Working around a known exception in unit tests?

Tags: c#, .net, nunit

I'm usint NUnit for testing a .NET Framework project. One method I'm trying to test returns the software version from the Assembly details using the following:

`object[] attributes = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AssemblyTitleAttribute), false);`

In normal runs this is fine, and the crash if it fails is wanted as this is important information to be able to continue. However, in tests, no assembly is created so this version cannot be found. The problem is each class I'm trying to test will get this software version as it's recorded.

Is there a way to work around this, fake an assembly or return a different value for the purpose of unit tests?

Comment: encapsulate the call to assembly in a method. mock the method for your test.

Comment: The method to get the assembly call is a couple of layers deep in inheritance; how do I go about making mocks of those and making sure they're called?

Comment: ...just like you go about mocking any other class. you have to wrap _all_ calls in that little helper class, tho. which, however, should've been done, anyway - many places touching the same external resource is a code smell. i'm afraid you have to put the work in and update all calls.

Comment: Please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32234257/how-to-inject-a-mock-assembly-for-use-with-moq). This might help

Answer (score 1):

This is not an ideal approach, but you can check if the NUnit framework is loaded into the current app domain to determine whether the code is running as part of a test or not:

```
public bool testRun = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Any(a => a.FullName.ToLowerInvariant().StartsWith("nunit.framework"));
```

You could then incorporate this into an if statement to set the value manually during tests:

```
object[] attributes;

if(testRun){
    //Set your manual value here
} else {
    attributes = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AssemblyTitleAttribute), false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the difficulty you have in testing is telling you something about your application, i.e. that it is not responding robustly to the manner in which it is being executed.

The SUT was designed on the assumption that this particualar assembly would only be called particular executable. But clearly that's not the case, since your tests are calling it as well. I think it would be completely reasonable to modify the SUT so that it uses some default value for the title when null is returned... or to simply not use the attributes for this purpose at all.

Some folks will say that the SUT should not be modified to make it more testable. But that's logically equivalent to refusing to modify the code for any of the other capabilities we want in our code, such as performing well or recovering from errors.